# Eloquent relation query not functioning

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm scratching my head over this database query and couldn't find out why it is not working.

It actually works if I try it directly on the `plays` table :

```php
Play::select(\DB::raw('COUNT(*) as plays'), \DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))
      ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
       ->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date')->get();
// returns the expected results
```

However, it does not work when I try to use it inside relation function ( returns empty array, while there is actually data ):

```php
 $artist->songs()->with(['plays' => function($q){
     $q->select(\DB::raw('COUNT(*) as plays'), \DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))
       ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
       ->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date');
  }])->get()->pluck('plays')->toArray();
```

**NB:** `$artist->songs()->with('plays')->get()` return the expected results

Comment: What relationship type is this ? Many to many?

Comment: @apokryfos No, artist hasMany songs | song belongsTo artist | song hasMany plays

Comment: for the eager loading relationship to work you will need to have an id of either parent or child on eager loading logic based on the relationship logic. Since you have a specific `select` without `song_id ` on the relationship logic it will not work, (And i don't think you can select id on the group by) it would be better if you fetch plays without groupBy and group it on collection retrieved

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to send `id` inside `select` statement.

```
   $artist->songs()->with(['plays' => function($q){
    $q->select(\DB::raw('COUNT(*) as plays'), \DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'id')
   ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek())
   ->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date');
   }])->get()->pluck('plays')->toArray();
```

Comment: Sadly, the same results.